# How to train Bixby to open Applications?

Tags: bixby

I want Bixby to open my application installed on my Samsung device. Like when i say **"open myApplicatonName"** it opens the specific application. Is there any way to achieve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `app-launch` https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.app-launch. This might help you with what you are trying to achieve.