# How do i connect my Application name with the code in Bixby?

Tags: bixby

I am trying to make a Bixby capsule to which will open my application when i say **"open myApplicationName"** and with the help of the this question 
[How to train Bixby to open Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101194/how-to-train-bixby-to-open-applications)

I learned that there might be way to do that But now am stuck on how do i do Bixby training. Which node do i connect for Bixby to understand what should be done when the command is executed

Comment: Do you want to just teach Bixby how to open your app without any other user interaction or would you like to open your application as the conclusion to a capsule solution you've built that a user would interact with first?

Comment: @Ameya i want to teach Bixby to open my application without any interaction just as i say "open myApplicationName" Bixby open that specific application

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to my comment, it looks like you're trying to cater to the following user flow:

1. User presses Bixby button or says "Hey Bixby"
2. User asks, "Open myApplication" (which is already installed on the user's device)
3. Bixby opens myApplication

The above use case does not require any capsule implementation or training on your end. This is something that Bixby can do already.

You can see this behavior by asking Bixby to "Open browser" or "Open [APP OF YOUR CHOICE]". Bixby will open your default browser or the app your requested.